# howto resolve UIDocumentStateSavingError and UIDocumentStateClosed

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

I have an iPhone-iCloud app. Now one document has the state `UIDocumentStateSavingError` and `UIDocumentStateClosed`. I can see the file on developers.icloud.com with the status "file upload is pending". But i don't know what to do now

When i try to delete the file with the code:

```
NSFileCoordinator* fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
[fileCoordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:fileURL options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting error:nil byAccessor:^(NSURL* writingURL) {
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    [fileManager removeItemAtURL:writingURL error:nil];
}];
```

the file is still there. I tried to delete the app on all devices but nothing changed. How can I delete this file or resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's long ago but still unanswered, so if your problem persists:

For me it works to prepend the [fileManager removeItemAtURL:...] with a [fileManager setUbiquitous:NO...] on the file and then let the fileManager delete the local copy.

Take care to use NSError and boolean result handling of the fileManager actions to be sure it really works. So if you get back an NSError you could see the reason why it failed. That's always good practice.

I stumbled into your question because I get the message "File upload is Pending" after such a deleted file is re-created even if it's some hours between deletion and creation.

Comment: Warning to anyone who reads this: if you prepend `[fileManager setUbiquitous:NO...]` to `[fileManager removeItemAtURL:...]` you are first removing the document from iCloud, which is removed from all your devices and then deleting your downloaded copy--so the file is lost forever! If you don't want this result, you can use `[fileManager evictUbiquitousItemAtURL:]`, which re-downloads the local copy.

Comment: Yes, you're right Anton - but that's exactly what the owner of this questions wants as result: delete the file from everywhere. At least that is how I understand his question...